# Как генерировать разные хэш ключи с одного компьютера

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Вопрос стал ребром. При установке facebook sdk на разных приложениях выбивает один и тот же хэш ключ.
Как можно его изменить? Желательно без использования виртуальной машины